# How to generate BIP85 Child Key using Bitcoin Explorer?

Tags: private-key, mnemonic-seed, command-line-options, bip85-deterministic-entropy

I've playing with 2 tools:

- [Mnemonic Code Converter](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) (site)
- [Bitcoin Explorer](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer) (CLI) - `bx` command

For the purpose of test I've used these tree BIP39 mnemonic words: `client mixed great`.

Using a site I've created successfully *BIP32 Root Key* using above words which matches `bx` output:

```
$ echo client mixed great | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new
xprv9s21ZrQH143K3UX3BhXusdpBUSLW3KVBCV6DGAuAKoXumU9chwDWjT9gcxjyFs8YdBxysyvZx2yC6snUBhb46wwXeq5xNqRjx5WkD8bbxYf
```

However when I'm trying to create a matching BIP85 Child Key (in Xprv format), it doesn't match:

```
$ echo client mixed great | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -i 0
xprv9v6WUZT3D9NryJcPMGBxrauhE42egVktC9mwLKFuZUjinZencdiZ21d43oye8rX83cEjfAKptfaoceUYctptAhc2UUM398Akf9n6qXzd8RQ

$ echo client mixed great | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -i 0 -d # a hardened key
xprv9v6WUZTBYouqAnZyHm1P76SvmRrmpvteFo2PhncirF6BNj2kr6qzTRJzJ41a5wwWKf35AjwtxDJEJ2U72H9g4LGj38Ytg2SzEfTQDVhEWB3
```

as the site reports the following key (in *Show BIP85* section, app format: Xprv, index: 0):

```
xprv9s21ZrQH143K3ke8WGywxcKxZQuH5p3FMzZRFiGawhHo7Nt58HpBpoHv4fZM2a1n2cxgMWipEfJ6XaaGi8pW9pEmjnigzNBVJGQSNwwGuqp
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you understand what to look for?

Not many tools have implemented BIP85

Pretty sure Libbitcoin-explorer (bx) is not one of them

Besides the iancoleman app, I only know of Coldcard & AirGap Vault.

See the spec for libraries

Python library implementation: https://github.com/ethankosakovsky/bip85

JavaScript library implementation: https://github.com/hoganri/bip85-js

https://github.com/scgbckbone/btc-hd-wallet